# Request: API Call to get list of users that flattred a thing

Tags: flattr

Would be great to get an API call that returns a list of users that flattred a certain thing. With this we could build websites like "People who support product x". Would be a great motivation for others to also flattr the thing, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was implemented last week.

http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#list-a-things-flattrs